# Count empty text fields in CASE sentence in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My column contains categories A, B, C or "empty" ( which means the record is not categorized).

I want to show the total number of  A's, B's and C's and the total number of records "Not categorized", and have tried the query below.

It does not work, however. It shows the correct number of A, B and C's but not the number of not categorized.

```
SELECT count(*) AS Quantity,
       CASE
           WHEN cf_ab_contacts.col_621 = '' THEN "Uncategorized"
           ELSE cf_ab_contacts.col_621  
       END AS `Category`
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY `cf_ab_contacts`.`col_621`;
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: [Edit] your question and include a minimal reproducible example, i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` statements on the tables, sample data for the tables as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text. No images! Also tag the version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: *or "empty"* Is it: NULL value? empty string? non-printed string? a literal 'empty'?

Comment: As a palliative you may use `COUNT(*) - COUNT(col_621 IN ('A','B','C')) AS Uncategorized`.

Comment: The column is never NULL. Thats why i thought I could use = ''

Answer (score 0):

Considering By Empty you mean NULL not a single space value, You have to test the condition with IS NULL predicate -

```
SELECT count(*) AS Quantity,
       CASE
           WHEN cf_ab_contacts.col_621 IS NULL THEN "Uncategorized"
           ELSE cf_ab_contacts.col_621  
       END AS `Category`
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY CASE
           WHEN cf_ab_contacts.col_621 IS NULL THEN "Uncategorized"
           ELSE cf_ab_contacts.col_621  
       END;
```

Comment: Thanks , Ankit Bajpai. The column is never NULL, so therefore i wrote '' in my query...

Comment: You may try with a space character ' '.

Comment: A space character still don't work. If I run the query without counting ( removing count() and GROUP BY) the query does list all records - with "empty" columns shown as "Uncategorized". 

But when aggregating it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry - but the query did work as intended - there was an error in my WHERE section which excluded empty columns.

Thanks to Ankit for your patience.

I'm not sure if I can delete this thread - I should never have posted it in the first place.